# python pymssql error with query execution

Tags: python, sql, pymssql

This is the pymssql query I am working with

```
query = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[helios_devops_data_curr] ("iipm.l3_it_org", "iipm.it_custodian","iipm.it_executive") VALUES ({}{}{})'.format("'Innovation and Technology'", "'bob tom'", "'bob tom'")
```

I'm using these values as an example, they are not the real values I'm trying to upload. However the errors are the same:

> 109, b'There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')

I'm not sure why these error is occurring as there's clearly 3 columns and 3 values being inserted.

Any help on this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format placeholders might need commas between them:

```py
query = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[helios_devops_data_curr] ("iipm.l3_it_org", "iipm.it_custodian","iipm.it_executive") VALUES ({}, {}, {})'.format("'Innovation and Technology'", "'bob tom'", "'bob tom'")
```

Looking at [the docs](http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html), it appears that `pymssql` might prefer you use C-style string-formatting symbols; maybe something like this:

```py
query = "INSERT INTO dbo.helios_devops_data_curr(iipm.l3_it_org, iipm.it_custodian, iipm.it_executive) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
params = ("Innovation and Technology", "bob tom", "bob tom")
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38381543/6768111) is another SO question with an example.

Comment: I'm really stupid, you're right I forgot the commas. Also yes I agree doing it that way is much more readable. Thanks for you're response. Marking as correct